# Angular 2: How to make an option in a select to selected based on a condition?

Tags: angular

I'm building a select element in a form from an array of objects. I want one of the options to be selected based on an attribute of the current object (`myobject.is_default`).

The basic template code looks like this:

```
<select formControlName="template">
  <option *ngFor="let t of templates" [value]="t.id">{{t.title}}</option>
</select>
```

I could now set the select option like this:

```
<select formControlName="template">
  <option *ngFor="let t of templates" [value]="t.id" [selected]="t.is_default ? 'selected' : ''">{{t.title}}</option>
</select>
```

But the problem I'm having is the HTML5 specs which state:

> The selected attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes :
>
> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true
>   value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
>   or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's
>   canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

The following are valid, equivalent and true:

```
<option selected />
<option selected="" />
<option selected="selected" />
<option selected="SeLeCtEd" />
```

The following are invalid:

```
<option selected="0" />
<option selected="1" />
<option selected="false" />
<option selected="true" />
```

That means: As soon as the selected attribute is present, the option is selected. So I need a way of not having the `selected` in all but one option.

I cannot use `ngIf` since it cannot be used together with `ngFor` on the same element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ngModel` to set what element should be the selected.

```ts
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" formControlName="template">
  <option *ngFor="let t of templates" [value]="t.id">{{t.title}}</option>
</select>
```

and in the class

```ts
var default = t.templates.find(v => v.is_default);
selectedItem = default && default.length && default[0].id;
```

Comment: this works but it is semantically wrong, one main intention of angular forms is to decouple form data from model data and you are not doing this with using ngModel

Comment: @Nickolaus thanks for the hint, but I didn't intend to give architectural lessons, only to point out what is missing to make it work.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - Perhaps you could update your answer to say that this is not the correct approach, but answers the question asked. Adding the correct approach (if you know it) would be good too

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using model driven approach, why not just set the value in model during the creation of form control group?

```
// select first (only?) default template
let defaultTemplate = this.templates.some((template) => template.is_default);
...
// create your form group and pass default template id as value for template select
this.yourForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    ...
    template: [defaultTemplate && defaultTemplate.id],
    ...
});
```

Comment: This is the better answer since there should be no need for [(ngModel)] in Reactive Forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do more complex stuff like get the text of the option, one way is to bind the option list to a complex object.

Create an interface for your object:

`export interface Day {
  id: number;
  text: string
}`

Then provide some values for it:

`this.days = [
  { id: 1: text: 'Monday'},
  { id: 2: text 'Teusday'}
]`

Then use it in your template to create your select list. It's important to use **ngValue** for the binding of the complex object.

`<select [(ngModel)]="configDatas.days" name="days">
  <option *ngFor="let day of days" [ngValue]="day">{{day.text}}</option>
</select>`

After that, displaying it is simple:

`<span>You selected DayId: {{configDatas.days.id}}, Text: {{configDatas.days.text}}</span>`

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/iSr9dpwa10tHwKM45FAE?p=preview